# Android Studio 2.3, cannot build gradle. Error 304

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-2.3

I am just installed Android Studio 2.3.
However, when I create any application, it always error.

For example, I just create new blank project.
It shows error: Error:Response 304: Not Modified has no content!
(see the screenshot)

[image]

I have already tried

1. Installing and reinstalling android studio, even delete the folder and not importing anything.
2. Invalidate cache and restart Android Studio

**UPDATE:**
I have already fixed this...
The problem is jcenter might now have the junit.jar or espresso.jar needed (or my internet connectin prevent me to fecth those). So, I change it to mavenCentral and it works

Before:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

After:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us build.gradle?

Comment: @SnehPandya that is completely different question. The link you gave is neither about Android Studio nor Android.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with the same thing for many hours

https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip download this link and extract it into C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\ now go to androidstudio -> setting -> build -> gradle edit gradle home as C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.3 disable offline work and save it

If it is not work diable testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' in gradle and retry this process

Comment: thank you, this might help me for offline mode! :D